# SIGSEGV SEGV_ACCERR in ios6

Tags: ios7, ios6

I have developed the ios App for a client . The application is crashing in regular interval in ios 6 . The application is GPS based and run background and foreground . Below is the crash report which I received:

```
libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3a7c25b0 objc_msgSend + 16

Foundation                          0x33306599 -[NSNotificationCenter 

postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 73
Foundation                          0x3330a05b -[NSNotificationCenter 
postNotificationName:object:] + 31
UIKit                               0x34a01307 -[UIApplication _performMemoryWarning] + 
103

libdispatch.dylib                   0x3abde4b7 _dispatch_client_callout + 23

libdispatch.dylib                   0x3abe5139 _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 253

libdispatch.dylib                   0x3abe317f _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 163
CoreFoundation                      0x32a72f3b __CFRunLoopRun + 1291

CoreFoundation                      0x329e5ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357

CoreFoundation                      0x329e5d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105

GraphicsServices                    0x365be2eb GSEventRunModal + 75

UIKit                               0x348fb301 UIApplicationMain + 1121

Can anybody let me know what is the above issue is about ?

Surjan
```

Comment: As the crash report says ([UIApplication _performMemoryWarning]), your app is terminated because it uses too much memory. You should analyze the situation with Instruments.

Comment: Which instruments you are talking about ?

Comment: Instruments is a tool set integrated into XCode. User guide is here <https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/instrumentsuserguide/Introduction/Introduction.html>. You can start it in XCode using product->profile. It is HIGHLY recommended to check your app regularly with instruments.

Comment: In addition to getting a memory warning, it looks as if some object in your application that listens for memory warnings may have been deallocated without unregistering as a listener.  (Hence the `objc_msgSend` frame on the stack.)